# Updating Reference in Visual Basic 6 Project

Tags: vb6

My Visual Basic application is using True DB Grid 5.0. I moved the application to windows 10 platform and downloaded True DB Grid 7.0.

**How can I upgrade the reference in my application both coding wise and reference wise** so that it starts using True DB grid 7.0 instead of True DB grid 5.0?

Right now even after  installing True DB grid 7.0 I, I am getting a missing reference saying

```
MISSING: APEX XARRAY object.
```

In my application, I am using the below line

```
Public GrdValArray as new XArray.
```

At this line, I am getting a compile error saying

> "cant find project or library"

Comment: check the new library in `Tools->References` with the VB Editor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a new project and try to add reference to `True DB grid 7.0`. Once it is done, I will try to play around a bit (or use sample code provided for the component), before upgrading my code. This will allow me to compare/judge what code changes are required to be done in old code. If all works fine, open the existing project. Remove the old references from `Tools->References` menu, Save the project. Close the VB6 IDE (closing the IDE will make sure, old references are completely removed from the memory - just to be very sure). Open the existing project. It will have missing references. Now add the new references from `References` menu, change the code (if required as per sample code), then save the project and compile.

Comment: I think this is a very good suggestion and approach. I would add thought that since this is a control. there may also need to be some updates to existing forms. Depending on whether or not the control is binary compatible with the older version will affect what has to be done int he forms (if anything). If the OP is not sure about this, I recommend following Mukul's suggestion and pasting there the reference lines from sample VBP files for both the old and new versions so we can compare.